# How do I extract an integer in a string?

Tags: c++

I get a line like: `"1001", Name`

I want to know how to grab the number in between the quotes without `atoi`.

The problem asks to make the function just grab the integer that's between two quotes in a string, then grab the name and place it in a string, but I don't understand that part.

Answer (score 2):

Search using the regular expressions:

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "\"1001\", John Martin";
    std::regex rgx("\"(\\d+)\", *([\\w ]+)"); // this will extract quoted numbers in any string
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx))
        std::cout << "ID: " << match[1] << ", Name: " << match[2] << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `std::istringstream`, eg:

```
std::string s = "\"1001\", Name";
std::string name;
int num;

std::istringstream iss(s);
iss.ignore();
iss >> num;
iss.ignore();
iss.ignore();
std::getline(iss, name);
```

Or

```
std::string s = "\"1001\", Name";
std::string name;
int num;

std::istringstream iss(s);
iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '"');
iss >> num;
iss.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
std::getline(iss, name);
```

Or

```
std::string s = "\"1001\", Name";
std::string name;
int num;

std::string::size_type start = s.find('"') + 1;
std::string::size_type end = s.find('"', start);
std::string snum = s.substr(start, end - start);

std::istringstream(snum) >> num;

start = s.find(',', end+1) + 1;
start = s.find_first_not_of(' ', start);
name = s.substr(start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the `std::string` functions `find`, `find_first_not_of`, and `substr` to parse the information.

You simply work your way down the original string finding the opening quote `"`, storing the index, then finding the closing quote, and its index, the integer string is the characters in between.

Next, you can use `find_first_not_of` locating the first character not a `",  \t"` (comma, space, tab), taking the name as the remainder of the original string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main (void) {

    std::string s = "\"1001\", Name", ssint, ssname;
    size_t begin, end;

    begin = s.find ("\"");                      /* locate opening quote */
    if (begin == std::string::npos) {           /* validate found */
        std::cerr << "error: '\"' not found.\n";
        return 1; 
    }
    end = s.find ("\"", begin + 1);             /* locate closing quote */
    if (end == std::string::npos) {             /* validate found */
        std::cerr << "error: closing '\"' not found.\n";
        return 1; 
    }
    ssint = s.substr (begin + 1, end - 1);      /* int is chars between */

    begin = s.find_first_not_of (", \t", end + 1);  /* find not , space tab */
    if (begin == std::string::npos) {           /* validate found */
        std::cerr << "error: no non-excluded characters found.\n";
        return 1; 
    }
    ssname = s.substr (begin);                  /* name is reamining chars */

    std::cout << "int : " << ssint << "\nname: " << ssname << '\n';
}
```

(**note:** always validate the results of `find` and `find_first_not_of` by ensuring the return was not `std::string::npos`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parse_str
int : 1001
name: Name
```

You can find details on all of the `string` library member functions at [cppreference - std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) Let me know if you have any questions.